# How do I download tracks from Garmin GPSmap 62 using GPS utility?

Tags: garmin

I think I have to open files from windows file manager and then save these, rather than the autoconnect facility available between other Garmin devices and GPS utility.. Is this correct or is there a way to get it to open the GPS transfer window automically on connection with this device model as this has the tick options for tracks download too? If I have to go via windows file manager, how do I differentiate tracks from waypoints and is there an easier way please?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? GPSUtility does seem to work fine with a GPSmap 62. Could you explain more about what issues you were experiencing?